# MS Access 2007 SQL: Select First Instance of Date/ID combo when id recurs on multiple dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to pull up the first instance of an animal being captured in a database. Each animal has an id code.

I'm currently using the Min date associated with each id code. This works well for the most part EXCEPT for returning a couple animals which were caught twice in the same day (once during an AM session and once during a PM session). My query returns both captures on that day, I only want the first one. However, I can't just filter out PM captures because sometimes animals were first caught in the afternoon.

Currently the dates and the AM/PM field are stored in a survey table, which is linked to the capture table by survey id. An AM survey from 8Jul2000 has a different survey id than the PM survey. Surveys were not entered in chronological order, so the survey id autonumber has no relation to chronology (making it useless for sorting).

I'm using two queries to do this now, one which figures out the first day an animal was caught and then a second which returns the capture records from that day. I need my results to be updateable. Here are my queries:

```
    SELECT [Capture Table].id_code, Min([Header (Survey) Table].Date) AS MinOfdate
    FROM [Header (Survey) Table] INNER JOIN [Capture Table] ON [Header (Survey) Table].survey_id = [Capture Table].survey_id
    GROUP BY ([Capture Table].[id_code]);
```

And then:

```
    SELECT [Header (Survey) Table].Date, [Header (Survey) Table].am_pm, [Capture Table].*
    FROM [First Capture subQuery] INNER JOIN [Capture Table] ON [First Capture subQuery].id_code = [Capture Table].id_code) INNER JOIN [Header (Survey) Table] 
    ON ([Header (Survey) Table].survey_id = [Capture Table].survey_id) AND ([First Capture subQuery].MinOfdate = [Header (Survey) Table].date
```

;

It seems like this could be done by sorting the results by am_pm and selecting the first instance of a date/id combo from that list, but I don't know how to apply the SELECT TOP to only those and still get all the records & fields I want beyond just those two (I didn't include some of the fields I want in the example for simplicity's sake).

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: Sample of data

**Header Table:**

---

```
    site     year     date         time     survey_id
    REFFOR   1988     3-Jul-1998   AM       192
    REFFOR   1988     3-Jul-1998   PM       180
```

**Capture Table**

---

```
    survey_id  record     species     id_code  capcode (1 = new capture, 2= recap)
    192        1          PERMAN      A100      1      
    192        2          PERMAN      A104      2
    192        3          PERMAN      A102      1
    180        4          TAMAMO      A103      1
    180        5          PERMAN      A100      2
    180        6          TAMAMO      A101      1
```

What I'm trying to do is make sure that the capcodes are correct. Which means (assuming the ones in my example are) the records with Record 1,3,4,&6 would be returned by my query.

However, right now my query returns records 1,3,4,**5** & 6, because A100 was caught twice on the 3rd of July, once in the AM survey (SurvId = 192) and once in the PM survey (SurvID = 180).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up eventually getting to work. It uses a lot of Parfait's answer, as well as the tips I found here: http://www.allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#TopN

```
SELECT st.site, st.year, ht3.date, ht3.time, ht3.trappers, ct3.trap_line, ct3.trap_no, ct3.species, ct3.id_type, ct3.[non-tag_id], ct3.id_code, ct3.age, ct3.sex, ct3.repro, ct3.wt_g, ct3.tail_mm, ct3.capcode, ct3.dead, ct3.comments, ct3.errata
FROM [Session Table] AS st INNER JOIN ([Header (Survey) Table] AS ht3 INNER JOIN [Capture Table] AS ct3 ON ht3.survey_id = ct3.survey_id) ON st.session_ID = ht3.session_id
WHERE ct3.id_code IN(
  SELECT ct2.id_code
  FROM [Header (Survey) Table] ht2 INNER JOIN [Capture Table] ct2 ON ht2.survey_id = ct2.survey_id
  WHERE (ct2.capcode = "2") AND ct2.capture_id IN
     (SELECT TOP 1 ct.capture_id                          
     FROM [Header (Survey) Table] ht INNER JOIN [Capture Table] ct ON ht.survey_id = ct.survey_id                            
     WHERE ct.id_code = ct2.id_code
     ORDER BY ct.id_code DESC, ht.date ASC, ht.time ASC) 
  ORDER BY ct2.id_code DESC, ht2.date ASC, ht2.time ASC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the subquery in `WHERE` clause matching on survey dates and conditioning subquery to main query's `id_code`. Resultset should be an updateable query.

```
SELECT h.Date, h.am_pm, c.*
FROM [Header (Survey) Table] h 
INNER JOIN [Capture Table] c ON (h.survey_id = c.survey_id) 
WHERE h.Date IN
      (SELECT Min(hsub.Date) AS MinOfdate
       FROM [Header (Survey) Table] hsub 
       INNER JOIN [Capture Table] csub ON hsub.survey_id = csub.subsurvey_id
       WHERE csub.[id_code] = c.[id_code]
       GROUP BY csub.[id_code]);
```

Comment: Looking at this what it seems to do is just pull up all of those fields. While this is part of what I need to do, and the updateable bit is great, it doesn't do this other thing I need. That is to select only the AM record when an animal was caught on AM & PM surveys on the Min(Date), while still returning PM captures if that is the only capture on Min(Date). Thank you for the answer though. I hope I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: Is AM/PM a time figure? As we can minimize that as well? Usually, it is helpful to illustrate by posting some data snippet.

Comment: No. It's just a label (because sometimes we have the time the traps were checked and sometimes we only have that they were checked/reset in the morning & evening). I will post a couple lines.